# Create a table and fill it with data through 2 nested loops in JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table, create-table

I found many similar questions but not my case.

```
function getRes(){

    var str = "";

    for(lat=1; lat<=2; lat++){

        for(lon=1; lon<=2; lon++){

       str += "Track "+lat+" "+lon+"<br>";

        }

    }
        return document.write(str);
}
```

I would to generate a table in html page with javascript then print the result of that function (above) inside it instead to write it simply to the html page, and better if it were with header.

With large numbers of data would take hours to do :(
Something would be like this.

```
<table border="1">
     <th>type</th>
     <th>latitude</th>
     <th>longitude</th>

 <tr>
 <td>Track</td>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>1</td>
 </td>

 <tr>
 <td>Track</td>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>2</td>
 </td>


 <tr>
 <td>Track</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>1</td>
 </td>

 <tr>
 <td>Track</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>2</td>
 </td>

<table>
```

Any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use a server-sided application? Or you only have the client part?

Comment: How are you getting you lats and longs? Are you actually typing them manually? If I were you I would find a latitude/longitude list on the internet, or even an API you can make a call to that returns JSON. After that, I would learn the ins and outs of JQuery and how it could help you create a table like this.

Comment: that was just example, i<=nbr  and the same for j<=another nbr.. I get nbr from input field with getElementById("").value

Comment: user must input this two numbers then by clicking, then a table will be generated

Comment: another possibility would exporting this as excel file but with header... many answered me but not enough to such "mission"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a very simple [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sf8qwejf/) of how create a table and fill it with td values:

```
function getRes(){
        var cont = document.getElementById('demo');
    var table = document.createElement("TABLE")
    var tr = null, td = null;
    tr = document.createElement("TR")
    td =document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = 'type';
    tr.appendChild(td);
   var td1 =  document.createElement("th")

  td1.innerHTML = 'latitude';
  tr.appendChild(td1);
  var td2 =  document.createElement("th")

  td2.innerHTML = 'longitude';
  tr.appendChild(td2);
    table.appendChild(tr);

    for(lat=1; lat<=2; lat++){

        for(lon=1; lon<=2; lon++){
                tr = document.createElement("TR")
       //str = "Track "+lat+" "+lon+"<br>";
                var td2 =document.createElement("td");
        td2.innerHTML = 'Track';

        var td3 =document.createElement("td");
        td3.innerHTML = lat;
        var td4 =document.createElement("td");
        td4.innerHTML = lon;
         tr.appendChild(td2)
        tr.appendChild(td3)
        tr.appendChild(td4)
                table.appendChild(tr);
        }

    }
     cont.appendChild(table); 
}
getRes()
```

Comment: thank you, that helped me and then I have my modifications :)